# C++11 Casting enums to ints

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, static-cast

I have a typed enum

```
enum side : int {_white=0,
                 _yellow=1,
                 _green=2,
                 _blue=3,
                 _red=4,
                 _orange=5};
```

However, using gcc-5, the compiler says it cannot use static_cast in the following scenario:

```
side value
function(static_cast<int *>(&value))
```

Why is that? Doing `static_cast<int>(value))` does not raise any error.

Comment: different types, shouldn't you use `reinpterpret_cast`?

Comment: You can convert a bool to a double, but that doesn't mean that a bool pointer can be meaningfully treated as a double pointer.

Comment: I thought a typed enum was essentially the same datatype though? Since it's typed as an `int`, the compiler should be able to accept that `static_cast` no? Obviously using `reinterpret_cast` works, but it's a bit of a code smell.

Comment: Yes, it's a code smell, but you're arguably trying to do something smelly. With `int* y`, you're allowed to do `*y = 44`. With `side* y`, you are not. You are removing a safety net.

Comment: @zneak... Thinking it through, it is smelly, makes sense.  I think a combination of your commment and Kerrek's would be an answer, I didn't really think through the bounds.  Not quite sure how to get rid of my code smell in my personal case though, probably going to have to stick with a reinterpret_cast, as I prefer it to using a million static_casts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pointer type cast is different than just a type conversion. Accessing through a pointer leaves the bytes the same but reads them differently. This is *not* safe for an enum because it can be different sizes of int.

A type conversion is safe though, because it converts the enum into an int as a copy. The original enum could be a single byte or two bytes but that doesn't matter once its copied into 4 or 8 bytes.